# JS If variable matches csv value push to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

Im trying accept user input and then if it matches the first value in a row of my csv push that entire row to an array.

I have a csv that looks like this.

```
City,Lat,Lon,Date
Seattle,47.6,122.3,2015 06 03
Spokane, 47.65, 117.42,2015 06 04
```

I accept user input like this.

```
var city = window.prompt("Which city are looking for",);
console.log(city);
```

Then if the city the user entered matches a city in the csv I want to push it to a new array. Here is the code I wrote for it, but its not quite working.

```
d3.csv("./some.csv", function(data) {
var lst = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
if (data.City[i] == 'city') {
lst.push(data[i]);
}
console.log(lst);
}
});
```

My desired output would look something like this.

```
[['Seattle',47.6,122.3,2015 06 03],
 ['Seattle',47.6,122.3,2015 06 05]]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see several problems.

```
if (data.City[i] == 'city') {
```

`data` is an array, each entry of which is an object with properties with the same names as the column heads. So, instead of `data.City[i]` you want `data[i].City`.

Also you are comparing the result with the string literal `'city'` instead of the variable `city`.

Finally [you should probably use `===`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) to avoid confusing results.

So this line should probably read:

```
if (data[i].City === city) {
```

The other thing is the data structure returned by D3 does not match what you are expecting. Instead of:

```
[['Seattle',47.6,122.3,2015 06 03]]
```

you will get

```
[ { City: 'Seattle', Lat: 47.6, Lon: 122.3, Date: '2015 06 03' } ]
```

If that is a problem for you, you could consider using the [d3.csv.parseRows](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parseRows) method which returns the data in the form you are expecting. In that case you will need to adapt the comparison line accordingly.

Comment: Oh the 'city' was a silly mistake on my part, but thanks for the suggestions. JS just kind of confuses me. d3.csv.parseRows is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks so much!